# StrPtr not recognized in visual basic (VS 2012)?

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS 2012:

Here's my situation:

I'm writing some code in visual basic that calls a dll function that I've written in C++ (also written using vs 2012). One of my function's arguments takes the wchar_t* data type, so I need to format my string from vb accordingly using StrPtr.

Here's my problem:

Visual Basic does not recognize StrPtr as a function. I get: 'StrPtr' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.'

What does this mean?

Comment: please do some online research of your own before you make a post. In fact, StrPtr is used to get memory address being referenced by a ptr. This link may help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/410cd02e-84fa-462f-90f5-d09962e8c749/strptr-equivalent-in-vbnet

Answer (score 2):

`StrPtr` is a VB6 function, it does not [exist in VB.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we34009t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> VarPtr, VarPtrArray, VarPtrStringArray, ObjPtr and StrPtr were
>   undocumented functions used to get the underlying memory address of
>   variables. These functions are not supported in Visual Basic .NET.

The equivalent .Net Framework method for wide strings is [Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni.aspx).

Although likely you should be using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to call a C++ funciton in which case the marshaling of a `String` to `wchar_t` is handled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This keyword has been [removed from the language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we34009t.aspx):

> VarPtr, VarPtrArray, VarPtrStringArray, ObjPtr and StrPtr are
>   undocumented functions used to get the underlying memory address of
>   variables. These functions are not supported in Visual Basic 2008.